# No More Gutter for Context Menu on Windows 7 (Only for Files)

Tags: windows-7, right-click, context-menu

I installed **Moo0 Rightclicker** and I believe after that the problems began. Notice the difference:

[image: Comparison of context menus for the desktop (left) and a file (right)]

On the left is what happens when I right click the desktop or a folder, and on the right when I right click a file (I've highlighted the region to which I'm referring in red). See how on the left there's a nice gutter with a bevel? Why has that stopped happening on the menu to the right? It's puzzling me and I've removed the Rightclicker application and still have this issue. Please, if anyone knows anything and can offer advice I would highly appreciate it. I realize this is a minuscule problem but it irks me. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Increase in weirdness in the form of foreign characters:

[image: Weirdness]

Comment: More info on moo0 right clicker [registry changes](http://www.uninstallapp.com/article/How-to-uninstall-Moo0-RightClicker-1.36.html) Take a look about halfway down the page.

Comment: I can't vouch for the info in the above website... main settings for context menus are located in the registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > folder > shellex > ContextMenuHandlers > LibraryLocation ... Is there anything other than the default in the Library Location? Otherwise, I'm stumped...

Comment: What is the default for "Library Location?" Just whatever is `(Default)`? The value is `{3dad6c5d-2167-4cae-9914-f99e41c12cfa}`.

Comment: `{3dad6c5d-2167-4cae-9914-f99e41c12cfa}` is the default. If you just highlight the ContextMenuHandler folder in the left column, do you entries beside the `default` which should have `(value not set)` in the DATA column?

Comment: No other entries...

Comment: I did a little more digging… Context menus are also in four other locations in the registry. 
From the command prompt type regedit
One at a time navigate to the following registry locations and check for entries other than the default
**1**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell`
**2**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx` 
**3**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` 
**4**`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

Comment: Ok, for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` I have the `(Default)` value as `none`. Is that correct? Also, for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` the default value is blank. Does that mean anything? Should there be a class ID there instead? Thanks, man. I hope you have some insight.

Comment: I have a favor to ask: for all those keys you listed, can you send me copies of yours as `REG` files? I would really appreciate that and I bet it has a chance of working. Thanks again! By the way, can you also post a picture of what the context menu looks like when you right click on files? That would be great.

Comment: I have the same setting for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`. For me `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` has the value in the data  column is set as, including the parenthesis: `(value not set)`. I can send you these as .reg files. Where do you want them sent?

Comment: I have been thinking about this still, I think I uncovered the solution. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` expanding `ContextMenuHandlers` will show you everything that has placed entries in the context menu. If the Moo0 Rightclicker entry is still there that might be what is causing your problem. Delete that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Should I expect these changes to be immediate? If you can, send me the REG files (gabriel@terrasoftlabs.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MAKE SURE TO BACK UP YOUR REGISTRY FILES BEFORE MAKING ANY CHANGES TO THE REGISTRY**

main settings for context menus are located in the registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` > `folder` > `shellex` > `ContextMenuHandlers` (I made an error earlier when I said `library Locations`, check the `ContextMenuHandlers` spot again.)

There should only be one file in that location called `default`. Context menus are also located in 4 other places that I know of:

One at a time navigate to the following registry locations and check for entries other than the default

**1** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\folder\shell` here the only entry I have is default / type = REG_SZ  / (value not set)

**2** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx` here the only entry I have is default / type = REG_SZ  / (value not set)

**3** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` here the only entry I have is default / type = REG_SZ  / value = none

**4** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` here the only entry I have is default / type = REG_SZ  / (value not set)

The default Context Menu when right clicking files looks like this:

[image: ContextMenu]

Comment: This sounds great but can you provide the default values for each of those entries? I see (value not set) and the like and am wondering if there is a GUID or something else that should be there instead. What are the values in your registry? Can you provide me each key? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "provide you each key"? Would you like me to send you the .reg files like you asked above? Or would you like screen shots of the binary info that pop up when "change binary data" is selected? I have set aside a folder with the .reg files like you asked, but I have no idea how to get them to you.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the long delay. I would love to have the REG files. Email them to gabriel@terrasoftlabs.com if you can. I appreciate it! Check out how distorted my menu has become.

Comment: As in look at the original post.

Comment: I emailed you 4 files. I hope they help. I also just found this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/. Good luck.

Comment: One of the above methods worked. All is well for my context menu again. Thanks!